# Css and js files references in user control created dynamically in placeholder

Tags: jquery, css, user-controls, placeholder

I created a user control with only one image. And I'm creating dinamically the user control with a placeholder in the web form.

In the user control I added references of CSS and js files, but doesn't have affect under the image.

NOTE: The image appear in the web form.

This is the user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="IVT_DisplayImage.ascx.cs" Inherits="Sublayout_IVT_DisplayImage" %>

<link href="~/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/css/imagezoom/imagezoom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
/>
<script src="~/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.imagezoom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#imgIdCard').ImageZoom();
    });
</script>
<div class="page">
    <div class="box cf">
        <div class="left"> <span class="demowrap">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgIdCard" runat="server" />
                    </span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the web form:

```
<div>
    <asp:placeholder ID="plhDisplayImage" runat="server"></asp:placeholder>
</div>
```

This is the code behind of the web form:

```
Sublayout_IVT_DisplayImage ivtDisplayImage = new Sublayout_IVT_DisplayImage();


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ivtDisplayImage = (Sublayout_IVT_DisplayImage) LoadControl("~/Sublayout/IVT_DisplayImage.ascx");
    ivtDisplayImage.ImageURL = "~/demo_assets/large/1.jpg";
    plhDisplayImage.Controls.Add(ivtDisplayImage);
}
```

And this is the structure of the folders:

```
css/
    demo.css
css/imagezoom/  
    imagezoom.css
js/
    jquery-1.8.3.min.js
    jquery.imagezoom.min.js
Sublayout/
    IVT_DisplayImage.ascx
Root:
    Default.aspx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a path problem,
try removing the `~` from the path's in the user control.
*Edit:* try replacing the `~` with `..`

**Edit:**
I see that your targeting the image via ID, but this is a `runat="server"` control. so it will be rendered with a different ID (you can see that in your HTML).

to target the image via ID (in JQuery), you will have to resolve the Client Id (you can find a lot of topics about how to do that), but you will not be able to do that in CSS.

**so instead:** you can give the image a class, and target the image via class selector (in JQuery and CSS). this is the easiest way.

**Final Solution (from the owner responce)**
I added the references in the web form and remove it to the user control and works good. Thank for your support, but indeed, the ID was a issue.

Comment: Hi, I changed to a class, but when I check the source in the tool to debug and script file, appear next error: GET http;//localhost......./js?jqeury 404 (Not Found) with all references files. That's why, I till have the problem.

Comment: the ID targeting was defently an issue.. about the references.. try changing the '~' with '..' int the control refernces..

Comment: OK.I hope someone will figure out what the problem is. but dont forget the ID thing.

Comment: I added the references in the web form and remove it to the user control and works good. Thank for your support, but indeed, the ID was a issue.